# Adding a custom property to my EF4 Model

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2010, t4, poco, entity-framework-4

Let's say I have two tables in SQL that I want to have an EDMX model generated from (for now, going with automagical generation for everything) using POCO T4 templates. Let's say our two tables are `Person (ID, FName, LName)` and `Comment (ID, PersonID, CommentText, CommentDate)` with a one-to-many relation between the two (i.e. you can make many comments about one person).

Getting my POCO entities generated from this is trivial and works beautifully. What I don't know how to do now, though, is to add a custom navigation property on my `Person` entity that represents the most recent comment for that person (eventually something even more complex than this will ultimately be needed). For now, it's okay that it's read-only but it would be nice to know how to handle an writable property too.

What is the proper way to do this? One thing to consider is that I'm serializing these entities so I will need them to be eager-loaded and persisted in a way that I can push them out to my UI with WCF in the middle (i.e. a custom hand-written property in an extension class that relies on lazy loading is not an option).

I've gotten pretty good at using EF4 for standard stuff, but now that I'm getting into this custom stuff, I'm not entirely sure how to do this in a best practice way.

Comment: Ideally, I want to call `Person.LatestComment` and have that be the same as calling `Person.Comments.OrderByDescending(c => c.CommentDate).FirstOrDefault()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a property is easy. Put it in a partial class, named the same as the entity. But if your property looks like:

```
get
{
     return this.Comments.OrderByDescending(c => c.CommentDate).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

...then it will work but you can't use it in an L2E query.

If you need L2E support, you can use [this technique](http://damieng.com/blog/2009/06/24/client-side-properties-and-any-remote-linq-provider).

Comment: The sample you provided won't work because I need this for L2E queries AND for the value to be serialized. I'll look into your other technique that you mentioned. BTW, thanks for stalking me and my questions and for all of the answers you're providing. ;-)

Comment: Looking into the other solution looks pretty involved (not necessarily in consumption but at least in understanding what's going on). As such, it's hard to have a gut feeling for how well it will work. Will it work with eager loading, explicit lazy loading, and in being serialized? And is there really not a way for me to do this within my EDMX mapping? I thought I was supposed to be able to have "interesting" mappings take place there so I can benefit from SQL optimized queries with those "interesting" mappings...

Comment: IMHO your entity is the wrong place to customize serialization. Adding custom properties to an entity is *different* than mapping. Yes, you can do "interesting" mappings to some degree (e.g., entity splitting), but custom properties is something else entirely.

Comment: The example with Person & Comment is a simplification of what I'm doing. More specifically, I'm working with you can think of as a person table & a scheduling table, & I'm trying to find the nullable "current task" of the person (a tad more complex than "latest comment"). In this scenario, I want to define in my DAL how to read in this data because it's very specific to the data in the scheduling table & the current time. All of this should be abstracted away in my DAL so nobody else knows about this. It just seems to me that this belongs in SQL Server albeit dynamically (i.e. my EDMX).

Comment: Unfortunately, I've been unable to use this method in a way where it provides Eager Loading.